How to set UI scaling to 2x?
I am using a machine who runs in 4K, and when I open Plawright, it is small, because I use UI scaling 200% and it opens at 100%.
How to launch Playwright with 200% UI scaling?

You can multiply the width/height values returned by page.viewportSize() by 2:
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.42.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  const url = "https://arngren.net";
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle"});
  const {width, height} = page.viewportSize();
  console.log(page.viewportSize()); // => { width: 1280, height: 720 }
  await page.screenshot({path: "before-viewport-increase.png"});
  await page.setViewportSize({width: width * 2, height: height * 2});
  console.log(page.viewportSize()); // => { width: 2560, height: 1440 }
  await page.screenshot({path: "after-viewport-increase.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Or hardcode some larger values in the viewport context option (default is 1280x720):
let browser;
(async () => {
  const url = "https://arngren.net";
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext({
    viewport: {width: 2560, height: 1440}
  });
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle"});
  console.log(page.viewportSize());
  await page.screenshot({path: "viewport.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Or try specifying null to let Playwright choose something system-dependent (presumably this will maximize/fill the screen):
const context = await browser.newContext({viewport: null});

